# Show hide select list depending on other select list value

Tags: javascript

The following code show one (of many hidden) child select list depending on the value of the parent select list. The script check if any value is selected (in the parent select list) and if so show the corresponding child select list. But if the user select a value for the parent select list, post the form, get a message that the child select list miss input and (most likely) presses back button in the browser the parent select list still has a value (I guess browser default) and the child select list is hidden which will most likely confuse the user.

How can this be solved?

Javascript:

```
    $('#parent-list').live("change",function() {
        var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $("#child-list-"+value).slideDown(200).siblings().hide();
        return false;
    });
```

HTML:

```
<select id="parent-list" name="parent">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  ...
</select>
<select id="child-list-1 style="display:hidden">
   <option value="a">a</option>
</select>
<select id="child-list-2 style...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a common problem, and as far as I know there is no perfect solution.

You need to find some way to check whether the page is in an invalid state, such as a refresh timer (`setInterval`) that can check any dependencies and re-render if necessary.

If the user presses the back button after a POST he will get a warning (at least in some browsers). Though you can not trust users to realize the issue...

EDIT: Also, why is the user redirected to another page for the error messages? Can you instead redirect him back to the form if an error occurs, or preferably perform the validations client side before form submission?

Answer (score 1):

I typically select an appropriate option on every page load, either through the code generating the HTML or in the JavaScript when the document is ready.

Comment: But the options are important so I dont want to risk that a user sends a validated form without actively selecting an option.

Comment: Then you'll need empty first options selected on first page load.  But re-select the user chosen option if showing the form again after user submission.

Comment: But that doesnt solve it seens the pressing the back button wont trigger that. At least in my testing.

Edit: Sorry that works of cours, had an error in my empty-code
Edit2: Guess I'll go with that, just annoying for the user to re-fill a field instead of the filled in fields just showing..